# Implementing `tf.data.Dataset.window` for CNN-LSTM in Time Series Forecasting

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm currently working on a project involving time series forecasting using a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) and Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) model. I've been following a guide I found on Medium (link [1]) and I'm trying to implement `tf.data.Dataset.window` to prepare the window data.

Here's the code snippet I've been working with:

```py
WINDOW_SIZE = 72
dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset_train)
    .window(WINDOW_SIZE, shift=1)
    .flat_map(lambda seq: seq.batch(WINDOW_SIZE))
    .map(lambda seq_and_label: (seq_and_label[:,:-1], seq_and_label[-1:,-1]))
)
```

However, I'm encountering issues with this approach and it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I'm unsure if I'm missing something in the implementation or if there's a better way to prepare the window data for a CNN-LSTM model.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to correctly use `tf.data.Dataset.window` in this context? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
[1]: https://shivapriya-katta.medium.com/time-series-forecasting-using-conv1d-lstm-multiple-timesteps-into-future-acc684dcaaa

Comment: what is the error you are getting? What is the dimensions of `dataset_train`

Comment: `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None, 5) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 5), dtype=tf.float32, name='lstm_60_input'), name='lstm_60_input', description="created by layer 'lstm_60_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 5).
`
and
`Input 0 of layer "lstm_60" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding a .batch(BATCH_SIZE) call at the end of the data pipeline. This groups the dataset into batches of BATCH_SIZE, which is necessary for training the model. Here's the corrected code:

```py
WINDOW_SIZE = 72
BATCH_SIZE = 32
dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset_train)
    .window(WINDOW_SIZE, shift=1)
    .flat_map(lambda seq: seq.batch(WINDOW_SIZE))
    .map(lambda seq_and_label: (seq_and_label[:,:-1], seq_and_label[-1:,-1]))
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
)
```

In this code, `WINDOW_SIZE` is the size of the window for the time series data, and `BATCH_SIZE` is the number of windows to include in each batch. The .window method creates a sliding window over the dataset, `.flat_map` flattens the data into a single dimension, and `.map` splits the data into features and labels. Finally, `.batch` groups the data into batches for training.

This solution should work for anyone trying to prepare windowed data for a CNN-LSTM model in TensorFlow.

Comment: with this code, you get a 72 long output too?